# Why is a narrowing conversion from int to float only needed if I brace-initialise an object?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initializer-list, type-narrowing

I ran into what I think is a weird thing:

```
#include <vector>

int numqueues = 1;
std::vector<float> priorities{numqueues, 1.f };
//^^^ warning: narrowing conversion of numqueues from int to float

//std::vector<float> priorities(numqueues, 1.f );
//^^^ No warning or error. And it's not because it's parsed as a function declaration
// as I can call push_back in main.

int main()
{
    priorities.push_back(1);// No narrowing conversion needed
}
```

I've tried this using a couple of compilers, this won't compile.

Edit: It's been said that the initializer_list takes priority, and that looks to be the case, but I tried to mimic std::vector and I don't get the narrowing conversion error in this example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
class MyVector
{public:
    MyVector(size_t s, float f) {
        std::cout << "Called constructor\n";
    }
    MyVector(std::initializer_list<T> init)
    {
        std::cout << "Called initializer list constructor\n";
    }

};

int main()
{

    MyVector<float> foo{ size_t(3), 2.f };
}
```

I've done exactly the same thing, initialised it with size_t and float, just like in the other example, this one compiles fine.

Comment: You used a constant for size in your test, not a variable. Here's your diagnostic https://wandbox.org/permlink/ECXJE0UmSeOl1Zk5

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica And what do the rules say about that? No narrowing conversion needed for constants?

Comment: More that the compiler is able to know if there is major loss in the conversion when it's a constant expression. So it doesn't have to alert on types alone.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So what happens if I reeaallly want to call that constructor of (size_t, float) and can't because of most vexing parse? Well, it's no ambiguous in that sense that it can be mistaken for a function declaration but I've seen cases where it was inferred as a function declaration when it didn't seem to me that it could possibly be.

Comment: The most vexing parse was always avoidable with a generous application of some extra parenthesis. Ugly, but avoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
std::vector<float> priorities{numqueues, 1.f };
```

the compiler uses the initializer list constructor.

```
vector(initializer_list<T>, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

The narrowing conversion for initializer lists is prohibited.

In this declaration

```
std::vector<float> priorities(numqueues, 1.f );
```

the compiler uses the constructor that specifies the number of elements and their initializer.

```
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

From the C++ 14 Standard (8.5.4 List-initialization)

> 2 A constructor is an initializer-list constructor if its first
> parameter is of type std::initializer_list or reference to possibly
> cv-qualified std::initializer_list for some type E, and either
> there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have
> default arguments (8.3.6). [ Note: **Initializer-list constructors are
> favored over other constructors in list-initialization**

and (13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization)

> 1 When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized such
> that 8.5.4 specifies that overload resolution is performed according
> to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects the
> constructor in two phases:
>
> (1.1) — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list
> constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of
> the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> (1.2) — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload
> resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
> the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the
> lements of the initializer list.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A
{
    A( std::initializer_list<float> )
    {
        std::cout << "A( std::initializer_list<float> )\n";
    }
    
    A( size_t, float )
    {
        std::cout << "A( size_t, float )\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a1 { 1, 1.0f };
    A a2( 1, 1.0f );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A( std::initializer_list<float> )
A( size_t, float )
```

As for your appended question then (8.5.4 List-initialization)

> 7 A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> (7.3) — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a
> floating-point type, **except where the source is a constant
> expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the
> target type and will produce the original value when converted back to
> the original type**, or

So in this list initialization

```
MyVector<float> foo{ size_t(3), 2.f };
```

the constant expression `size_t( 3 )` that fits into the type float is used.

For example if in the above demonstrative program you will write

```
size_t n = 1;

A a1{ n, 1.0f };
```

then the compiler should issue a message about narrowing conversion (at least the MS VS 2019 C++ compiler issues such an error message).

Comment: It has a constructor that takes a size_t and a float, why isn't it calling the constructor? I use brace-initialisation instead of ( ) to avoid most vexing parse.

Comment: @Zebrafish The initializer-list constructor has a priority.

Comment: @Zebrafish See also my appended answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference on list initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
> prohibiting the following:
>
> - ...
> - conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value can be stored
>   exactly in the target type

Generally, a list initialisation doesn't do implicit conversions for you. Also, because `std::vector` has a constructor `vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`, it is the one that is being called to construct the `vector`.

Comment: std::vector has a constructor that in the example's case takes a size_t and a float, why isn't it calling the constructor?

Comment: It is calling the constructor, it's just using the elements of the list, and it is not allowing narrowing conversions.

Comment: There's a constructor vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()); How does it call this with an initialiser list? There is a constructor that takes an std::initializer_list, but I called I put an int and a float there, shouldn't it have called the size_t, float constructor?

Comment: I believe it doesn't, it calls the constructor with `vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`